# Matrix of linear transformation - $I_n$ for some base?

Tags: linear-algebra

$f:X\to X$ is linear transformation, $\dim X  < \infty$. $f$ is isomorphism.  Then matrix of $f$ is equals to $I_n$ for some base of $X$.

I know that it is not true, but I can't why. Can you explain it me ?

Comment: You can find two bases $B$ and $C$ of $X$ such that the matrix of $f$ becomes $I_n$ when the basis $B$ is used for its domain and the basis $C$ is used for its target. But you cannot make this work for $B=C$ unless $f$ is the identity map.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take for example

$$f=\begin{pmatrix}0&1\\1&0\end{pmatrix}$$

This matrix is invertible (say over $\;\Bbb C\;$ for definitiveness), but it isn't similar to the identity matrix (trace, for example...) .

As the comment remarks, I'm assuming the usual agreement that for linear *operators* the same basis is chosen for both the domain and the codomain.

Comment: Your assumption is ok.  We can tell that all matrixes of endomorphism are similar. Because of your $f$ is not similar to $I_n$ and $f$ is proper matrix of isomorphism (in particular endomorphism ) then $I_n$ can't be matrix of transformation. Yeah ?